# reledmac/reledpar: parskip between paragraphs

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I want to use the `reledmac`/`reledpar` packages and want to have a skip between the paragraphs. Therefore I use the `parskip` option of the [Koma-script class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) `scrreprt` but without any effect:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrreprt}

% Better linebreaks
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[]{reledmac}

\usepackage[]{reledpar}
% reledpar configuration
\setlength{\columnrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            \pend            
         \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    %
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            \pend       
         \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Remark About the Accepted Answer

`\autopar` inserts `\pstart…\pend` for each empty line in the code. Therefore you need an empty/blank line before the `\endnumbering` command. Otherwise you will get an error (`! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>\endnumbering`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you must understand that reledmac / reledpar, for some internation reason, break the normal system of paragraphing of LaTeX.  What is really paragraph for reledmac/reledpar are the `\pstart … \pend` unit. Especially, with reledpar, if you want paragraph to be synchronized, and that is the aim of reledpar.

In order to help you to have to typing every `\pstart…\pend`, reledmac provides a `\autopar` command, which insert the `\pstart…\pend` structure for each empty line in the sourcefile (except with some restriction, explained in the handbook of reledmac).

And so, reledmac allow you to insert any arbitrary command after every `\pend` typesetting, and, for example, vertical spacing (`\vspace`).

So a MWE would be

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrreprt}

% Better linebreaks
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[]{reledmac}

\usepackage[shiftedpstarts]{reledpar}
% reledpar configuration
\setlength{\columnrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\AtEveryPend{\vspace{\parskip}}

\begin{document}


\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \autopar
                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text


                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text   

         \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    %
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \autopar
                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text              

         \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

ps: you should look on §3.2 of reledmac handbook. The optimization options are very useful

Comment: I just tried it. When I remove the blank line before **\endnumbering** then I get an error saying **! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>\endnumbering**. Is that an expected behaviour?

Comment: yes, it is (even if the message could be clearer)