# Reledmac and KOMA-Script: How to fix parskip when enumerating paragraphs?

Tags: koma-script, reledmac, parskip, reledpar

I try to use the `reledmac` package to enumerate paragraphs in my document, which I generate with `pandoc`.

Unfortunately, the commands `\pstart` and `\pend` needed for the enumeration break the `parskip` control of the KOMA-Script classes. How can I re-enable consistent spaces between headlines, lists and paragraphs?

**Related Question**:

- [reledmac/reledpar: parskip between paragraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308375/reledmac-reledpar-parskip-between-paragraphs)
  (solution does not work here – the spaces get too large)

### Preview of MWE

[image: Preview of MWE]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=14,a4paper,parskip=true]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{reledmac} 

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\beginnumbering
\numberpstarttrue
\sidepstartnumtrue
\labelpstarttrue

\section{Intro}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia.

\begin{itemize}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{itemize}

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia.

\section{Paragraph Numbering}

\pstart Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.\pend

\pstart Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia.\pend

\begin{itemize}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{itemize}

\pstart Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia.\pend


\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, reledmac is not conceived to use enumerating paragraph. It is a pending issue, but, for now, I have not time yet to fix it. You can make fake list, using \\ and $\bullet$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you only have to define an new command which steps a counter and prints the counter:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=14,a4paper,parskip=true]{scrartcl}
\newcounter{parnum}
\newcommand*\parnum{%
  \par\leavevmode
  \refstepcounter{parnum}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\theparnum.\quad}%
}

\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Intro}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia.

\begin{itemize}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{itemize}

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia.

\section{Paragraph Numbering}
\parnum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.

\parnum Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia.

\begin{itemize}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{itemize}

\parnum Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia.
\end{document}
```

[image]